# I am not able to load the image in the terminal in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I have few .DCM files which i want to process. i am trying to extracxt the image in jpeg format from the following code. i can see the image in the plot section. but i am not able to save it via terminal.can you give some insight how i can proceed further. and i will be glad if you can tell why its output is not piping out in the "im1"

```
#load the necessary libraries
library(oro.dicom)
library(oro.nifti)
library(raster)
library(plot.matrix)
#read the file
dcm = readDICOMFile("1-01.dcm")
#extract Image
dcm_extract = dcm$img
#visualize the image
im1 <- image(raster(dcm_extract))
#dimensions of im1
dim(im1)
NULL
```